# ¿Cómo guardar los datos de un formulario en C#?

Tags: c#

Buenas a todos.

Estoy acabando una práctica que consiste en una hoja de personaje para Windows (estilo rol).

Esa hoja de personaje tiene una serie de controles en los cuales el usuario puede crear un personaje y guardarlo (ya se puede crear un personaje y, por supuesto, se guarda en un archivo txt).

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Uno de los puntos de la práctica es **conseguir guardar "el progreso" actual** cuando un usuario cierra el formulario, es decir:

- Si un usuario cierra la aplicación, lo que haya insertado y no insertado se guardará y, cuando se vuelva a abrir la aplicación se mostrarán esos datos.

La verdad es que no se cómo comenzar a hacer esa parte y necesitaría ayuda.

Había pensado hacer en el evento de FormClosing guardar los datos en un archivo txt pero, no sé cómo acceder a los datos.

Como ejemplo, para guardar un personaje, creo un objeto de la clase personaje y llamo a las funciones correspondientes (no sé si tendría que hacer esto, o si tendría que hacer una clase a parte).

**(Adjunto pastebin porque no me deja poner todo el código en la pregunta)**

[Clase Form1](http://pastebin.com/gQfL9zgn)

[Personaje](http://pastebin.com/9VNd5c3A)

Me ayudaría bastante saber cómo recorrer eficientemente todos los controles del formulario en sí para ir añadiendo lo que contengan de manera dinámica.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: al final, ¿Cómo consideraste el guardar y recuperar la información del formulario?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guardar la configuración debería ser concisa, optima y rápida de leer. Asimismo, aprovechar la función [DataBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx) de los controles de windows form.

En mi ejemplo consideré una estructura JSON, guarda la información mínima que podrá *deseriarizarse* de forma rápida:

Generar clase Persona con sus propiedades que se relacionarán con los controles.

```
public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
}
```

La programación de recuperar y guardar la información sería:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FormBindingToClass
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Persona Persona { get; set; }
        private const string RutaArchivo = @"C:\Persona.json";

        private void CargarInformacion()
        {
            Persona = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persona>(File.ReadAllText(RutaArchivo));

            foreach (var prop in Persona.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                foreach (Control control in Controls)
                {
                    if (control.Name.Substring(3) != prop.Name || !prop.CanRead) continue;

                    if (control is TextBox)
                    {
                        //((TextBox)control).Text = prop.GetValue(Persona, null) as string;
                        ((TextBox)control).DataBindings.Add("Text", Persona, prop.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void GuardarInformacion()
        {
            File.WriteAllText(RutaArchivo, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Persona));
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CargarInformacion();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            GuardarInformacion();
        }
    }
}
```

La información guarda en el archivo **Persona.json** es:

```
{"Nombre":"David","Apellido":"Sanchez"}
```

Y sobre el diseño del formulario es sencillo (para este ejemplo), 2 controles TextBox. Tendrán los nombres: **txtNombre** y **txtApellido**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el tratamiento de JSON, utilizo [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente te recomiendo que guardes el progreso en un documento XML. Es sencillo de leer y escribir, ya que lo puedes ir guardando de acuerdo a "categorías".

En fin, si deseas guardar lo que tienes en el Form, lo ideal es declarar un evento FormClosing, y dentro de este, escribir el código asociado a la captura y guardado de la información de la clase (recuerda, FormClosing != FormClose).

La genialidad de XML es su sencillez para recuperar la información, por lo que declaras un par de lineas en un evento Load, y los estados de la clase guardada pueden ser recuperados facilmente.

Saludos!